# How can we mix the line type in multi-lines graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph, line

Given that I have data with several variables as shown in the picture. Each variable may be significant (continuous line) and sometimes is not significant (dot line).
Can anyone share a solution in R-program for this task? Many thank for attention.
[Example from Python][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag3bz.png***emphasized text***

Comment: It is up to the person posting the question to provide test code in R and data.  Please provide this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on in the picture that you provided. I'm assuming that you're really only concerned with how you can set one line to be a solid continuous line and another as a dotted line. You would do this with the `linetype` argument when using the `ggplot2` package.

Here is a quick reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

midwest %>%
  filter(PID < 1000, str_detect(category, 'H')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = PID, y = popdensity, group = category, linetype = category, color = category)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dotted', rep('solid', 14)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Harison Jones! Actually, I can control the line type and color for each line, but I get in stuck with the mixed line type for one line. For your example, could you change the blue line type to a dotted line when its value is under 10000?